# Disable transition animation

Tags: javascript, animation, vue.js, css-transitions, vuejs2

How can I disable animation for  for some cases?

https://jsfiddle.net/4b3nxv7n/

```
<div id="flip-list-demo" class="demo" :class="{'animate': animate}">
  <button v-on:click="shuffle">Shuffle</button>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="animate"/>
  <transition-group name="flip-list" tag="ul">
    <li v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </transition-group>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#flip-list-demo',
  data: {
    animate: true,
    items: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  },
  methods: {
    shuffle: function () {
      this.items = _.shuffle(this.items)
    }
  }
})

.animate .flip-list-move {
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

Here is a modified transition group example with checkbox to toggle animation. I use css class to disable animation when it is necessary. Commonly it works okay but there is a bug:
if you unselect the checkbox, then click "Shuffle", then select the checkbox back, the animation still does not work.
As far as I can see using Chrome dev tools transition classes are not applied to elements for this case.

Another way how I tried to solve this was to change transition name property. But I have the same bug.
https://jsfiddle.net/61vLtaxn/

```
<div id="flip-list-demo" class="demo">
  <button v-on:click="shuffle">Shuffle</button>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="animate"/>
  <transition-group :name="transitionName" tag="ul">
    <li v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </transition-group>
</div>
new Vue({
  el: '#flip-list-demo',
  data: {
    animate: true,
    items: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  },
  computed: {
    transitionName: function () {
        return this.animate ? 'flip-list' : 'disabled-list'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    shuffle: function () {
      this.items = _.shuffle(this.items)
    }
  }
})
.flip-list-move {
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

Do I understand something wrong about transition or this is vue bug?

Comment: It works for me on Mac/Chrome

Comment: @RoyJ it doesn't work for me on Mac/Chrome. Make sure to run the fiddle and follow the steps to reproduce before doing anything else (that got me at first). Grigory, I think it's a bug

Comment: You're right: I shuffled before unchecking the box. If you shuffle first, you can check and uncheck and the shuffling works as expected. If you uncheck before ever shuffling, it will never do the transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug and it's been [reported on their GitHub](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6006).

The workaround they gave was to add a `key` attribute to the `transition-group`:

```
<transition-group :name="transitionName" :key="transitionName" tag="ul">
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tvydLvuo/)

---

The workaround I found was to explicitly add a `disabled-list-move` class (to your second example) with an almost-instantaneously fast transition (`transition: transform 0s` caused the same issue):

```
.flip-list-move {
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.disabled-list-move {
  transition: transform 0.0000000001s;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xxto4nne/)

Comment: I can't tell if this is related, but using `@enter` with the `transition-group` tag in this example doesn't work. [The docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Staggering-List-Transitions) suggest it should.

Comment: @Grigory the bug has been reported and in the process of being fixed, but they gave a workaround in the meantime. See my edit

Comment: Should it not be called on a shuffle?

Comment: @RoyJ that's my understanding. Enter is just called when an item is added.